# Conditional load css for IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why is this ie6.css file not loading on IE6?
The 'TEST 123' text does show.
(the css works if I remove the condition)

I'm testing this on a virtual box with xp and IE6 from http://modern.ie

(I know the _ and * css hacks, but I need a very different layout on IE6)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Web/css/ie6.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CE Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p>TEST 123</p>
    <![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ~ (tilde) in path does not work in plain HTML, can you try using a full url

Comment: That was the problem. I dragged the css file in Visual Studio and it generated this url. Thanks!

Comment: I only had to remove the ~ and everything works.

Comment: That's good to hear. Happy coding Roeland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the full url.
When using the syntax like that it won't work in your browser.

```
"http://yourwebsite.com/Web/css/ie6.css"
```

Comment: This solved it, but strange that the url did work without the conditiion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

**Target IE 7 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Web/css/ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

OR

**Target IE 6 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Web/css/ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```